# Is it possible to use Box2D or Chipmunk in Swift & Cocos2d?

Tags: box2d, xcode, swift

I am new to iOs programming.

I wonder whether it is possible to use Box2D physic engine in Cocos2D with Swift. I am asking because I started to learn Swift. And I create Xcode project from Spritebuilder with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use box2d with cocos2d, you can check some tutorials on it or refer this http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Box2D